# Prevent xautolock/i3lock when watching fullscreen video

Tags: fullscreen, lockscreen, i3, user-inactivity

I use the i3 window manager and have

```
set $Locker i3lock --color=000000 && sleep 1
exec --no-startup-id xautolock -time 5 -locker "$Locker"
```

in its config file, so that it locks after 5 minutes.

The problem is that the 5 minutes timer counts down even when I'm whatching a video, which I definitely don't like. (Btw, I usually watch movies with `mplayer`, but sometimes I go on streaming websites as well, using `qutebrowser`.) On the contrary, I'd like to prevent `xautolock`s action in such situations.

One possible solution I was thinking of is changing the second line to

```
exec --no-startup-id myscript -time 5 -locker "$Locker"
```

where `myscript` is a bash/whatever script/program passing all options to `xautolock` only if I'm *not* watching some video stuff. But I don't know what to check with this hypothetical script.

Comment: I'm having lots of trouble with this too. You can use the -corners setting of xautolock, so you just move your mouse to the corner, and it won't sleep, but unfortunately some players will always show the overlay if your mouse is in a corner!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One possible way to do this, without needing to implement all of xautolock's options in `myscript` would be to write your `$Locker` as a script or program to determine if the conditions are met to prevent locking. Otherwise, call the screen locker:

```
xautolock -locker should_screen_lock.sh
                                   |
                   Yes <- fullscreen YouTube? -> No
                    |                            |
                  Abort                         Lock
```

You can use `xprop -root` to learn the ID of the active window in the window manager and `xprop -id` against that ID to see if it's running in fullscreen mode.

From there, it's just putting the two together and calling your window locker (`i3lock` in this case, but you could also have that as a custom script for a fancier lock screen).

[Here's my attempt](https://github.com/clayboone/scripts/blob/master/auto_lock_screen.sh) at doing exactly this. Of note, I don't run `xautolock` from i3's config: It's a systemd user service. The locker (`lock_screen.sh`), however, is bound to a the keyboard so that I may bypass xautolock in case I have something in full screen.

Comment: Wow, this is a really good anwer, thank you! Your code is extremely readable, security-compliant (as far as I know what security is), and reasonably short! Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: your bash scripting is very logical and nice. I wonder if there's a way to tell if the youtube video is playing or not.

Comment: Indeed a very nice answer! Thank you!